# How to get normal vector of the object hitting while using OnTriggerEnter?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, game-physics, unity3d-2dtools

When I use On**Trigger**Enter method it doesn't return normal vector of the collider i'm hitting. If I would use On**Collision**Enter it can do so as far as i know. But i need to work with triggers not collisions, so I need a way to read the normal of the trigger collider that was hit.
Is it possible in any ways?
I tried to work with bounds of the collider but didn't get too far.

p.s. I'm interested in 3d physics and in 2d also. Any variant would be welcome.
p.p.s. it's *Unity3d*

Comment: not sure what your p.p.s is about since your tag tells us you are using Unity.

Comment: @wooden_coder were you able to find a solution to your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Collision Action Chart in the Unity Manual under [Colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html). This will tell you what messages can be detected between different setups of objects.